# Loop over host_vars of hosts in an ansible hosts group in jinja

Tags: ansible, jinja2

## Setup

### Inventory

My inventory contains two groups: worker and main. Worker contains 5 nodes and main contains 1 node.

### Host_Vars

Every node has a `host_vars` file containing `name` and `description`.

## What I am looking for

### Jinja

A Jinja template that loops over the `host_vars` of all nodes in a group.

#### Pseudocode

I would like to loop over the host_vars like this:

```
{% for node in groups["nodes"] %}
Name: {{ node.name }}
Description: {{ node.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Possible Result

```
Name: Nam1
Description: Des1
Name: Nam2
Description: Des2
...
```

### My "Solution"

But I fail to see how I can do this elegantly. A simple solution that I currently use is to hold a vars file containing all the `host_vars` information. That vars file is known by every target and by that I can access all node information from every target. However, this isn't the best solution I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```
{% for node in groups["nodes"] %}
Name: {{ hostvars[node].name }}
Description: {{ hostvars[node].description }}
{% endfor %}
```

For a documentation of `hostvars` see [Ansible special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)

To go a bit further, note that if your inventory looks like:

```yaml
---
nodes:
  hosts:  
    server1.mydomain.com:
    server2.mydomain.com:
```

1. `inventory_hostname` will contain the full name
2. `inventory_hostname_short` will contain the name before the first dot (i.e. `server1` for the first server in that list).

You can check the above link for those special variables as well. So this could probably replace your custom `name` variable (saving one variables in your host specific files) and your template would then look something like:

```
{% for node in groups["nodes"] %}
Name: {{ hostvars[node].inventory_hostname_short }}
Description: {{ hostvars[node].description }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the custom name variable was only used to represent "some data". Thank you very much for your explanation!