# Access group vars from target outside of the group

Tags: ansible

Similar to [Loop over host_vars of hosts in an ansible hosts group in jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75653136/loop-over-host-vars-of-hosts-in-an-ansible-hosts-group-in-jinja/75653196#75653196), I would like to access a `group_vars` with a static name.

So let's say I have two nodes: `main` and `worker`. `main` is in group `main`. In the file `group_vars/main` there is:

```yaml
special_value: 42
description: 21
```

And in an Ansible script running on `worker` I want to access the variables of `main`. If `main` would be a `host_vars` I could use `hostvars["main"]`. However, the same syntax doesn't seem to exist for groups: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html

This example is simplified, but in the end I intend to access the data to fill a Jinja template.

Comment: Do you want to apply [*precedence*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) to *main* variables in *worker*? If you want both *main* and *worker* to get the same *group_vars* create links to the same file. This way the [*precedence*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) will apply. Or, do you want to get 'raw' *main* group_vars in *worker* without precedence? For example by *include_vars*?

Answer (score 0):

You can target any node of the group `main`, for example, the first one of the group with `groups.main.0`, then, you just fall back on what you know already: `hostvars[groups.main.0].special_value`.

---

Given the inventory:

```yaml
main:
  hosts:
    main:
    worker:
  vars:
    special_value: 42
    description: 21
```

And the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |-
      special_value is {{ hostvars[groups.main.0].special_value }}
      description is {{ hostvars[groups.main.0].description }}
```

This yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    special_value is 42
    description is 21
```

---

This way of doing it is actually the one proposed in the frequently asked question page of Ansible:

> ### How do I access a group variable?
>
> Technically, you don’t, Ansible does not really use groups directly. Groups are labels for host selection and a way to bulk assign variables, they are not a first class entity, Ansible only cares about Hosts and Tasks.
>
> That said, you could just access the variable by selecting a host that is part of that group, see [first_host_in_a_group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#first-host-in-a-group) below for an example.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-access-a-group-variable*</sup>

Comment: There are two problems with `hostvars[groups.main.0]`. 1) The group `main` must be in your current inventory. 2) *host_vars* of *groups.main.0* can override *group_vars* of *main*.

Answer (score 0):

For example, declare the paths to the *group_vars* in the inventory and playbook directories

```yaml
  inventory_groupvars_main: "{{ inventory_dir }}/group_vars/main"
  playbook_groupvars_main: "{{ playbook_dir }}/group_vars/main"
```

and include the variables in a play

```yaml
    - block:
        - include_vars: "{{ inventory_groupvars_main }}"
          when: inventory_groupvars_main is exists
        - include_vars: "{{ playbookgroup_vars_main }}"
          when: playbook_groupvars_main is exists
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

---

Example of a complete project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   └── main
│   └── hosts
└── pb.yml

2 directories, 4 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/inventory/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```ini
shell> cat inventory/hosts
[worker]
worker1
worker2
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/group_vars/main 
special_value: 42
description: 21
```

```yaml
shelll> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: worker

  vars:

    inventory_groupvars_main: "{{ inventory_dir }}/group_vars/main"
    playbook_groupvars_main: "{{ playbook_dir }}/group_vars/main"

  tasks:

    - block:
        - include_vars: "{{ inventory_groupvars_main }}"
          when: inventory_groupvars_main is exists
        - include_vars: "{{ playbookgroup_vars_main }}"
          when: playbook_groupvars_main is exists
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: |
          special_value: {{ special_value }}
          description: {{ description }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [worker] ********************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************
ok: [worker1 -> localhost]

TASK [include_vars] **************************************************************************
skipping: [worker1]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [worker1] => 
  msg: |-
    special_value: 42
    description: 21
ok: [worker2] => 
  msg: |-
    special_value: 42
    description: 21

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
worker1: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
worker2: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```